# Bug while printing a Bootstrap table on Chrome

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have a weird bug when I want to print my webpage under Chrome. I display a table using Bootstrap, which fits perfectly the screen size (whatever the screen size is). When I want to print the webpage under Chrome, the table is cropped, whereas the printing layout is perfect using Firefox.

I have managed to reproduce my bug on JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11668/).

The html code of my table is :

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="...">
            <td>...</td>
            <!-- ... -->
        </tr>
        <tr class="separator empty" />
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Do you have any idea to fix this issue?
Maybe using different Bootstrap css class for the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying a initial zoom size printed all the contents.

```
@media print {
    body {
        zoom: .8
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11671/

Comment: Thank you, it's still a weird bug but your workaround did the trick

Comment: Just a workaround, and not a fix.  Didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug in Bootstrap 3 that it seems has been put off till Bootstrap 4.  The bug has to do with responsiveness being applied in printed styles.

In my case, changing all my `col-sm-*` classes to `col-xs-*` worked great.